# After closing js overlay my page content is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Initially all my page content is shown. When I click the button (in the footer) called 'about us' my overlay covers the page and shows some info. When I am done reading and I hit the 'X' in the right corner the overlay closes (as it should do) but I am left with a webpage without my content. The same content that was there prior to clicking the 'about us' button is now hidden.

Why is this?

**My HTML:**

```
<footer>
<a  id="footer_" href="#" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Over ons </a>
</footer>
```

**My JS:**

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.height = "0%";
}
```

**My CSS:**

```
.overlay {
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {overflow-y: auto;}
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
```

**the default content on the page:**

HTML:

```
<div id="content" >

            <!-- Intro -->
            <article id="menu_a">
                <h2>Introduction</h2>
                <figure>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Intro image"/>
                </figure>
                <p>
                some text here bla bla bla....
                </p>
            </article>

</div>
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/t60623gj/

Comment: Can you share a fiddle showing this problem ?

Comment: @abhishekkannojia pls see edit :)

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using jQuery for the job, would make it much easier.

Something along the lines of :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#footer').click(function() {
    $('#myNav').slideUp();
 });
  $('.closebtn').click(function() {
    $('#myNav').slideDown();
 });
});
```

Depending on what you want your nav to do exactly.

Also there seems to be a problem with your fiddle - it only displays your footer.

**EDIT**

Or if you want to manipulate the height attribute of the element you can use [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I tried it but it does nothing.